# 'who' has no output

Tags: arch-linux, users

I'm new to Arch Linux, and I just built my system up. But when I ran `who` in urxvt, I got nothing. Anyone know what's going on?

BTW. I use Slim + OpenBox. And here are parts of my configure files.

rc.conf:

```
DAEMONS=(syslog-ng @network netfs dbus !bluetooth @crond @alsa @wicd @hal )
```

.xinitrc:

```
#! /bin/bash

xscreensaver &
rl=$(runlevel | grep -o [0-6])

case $rl in
    4) exec openbox-session;;
    5) exec gnome-session;;
#4) exec ck-lauch-session openbox-session;;
#5) exec ck-lauch-session gnome-session;;
esac
```

inittab:

```
id:5:initdefault:

rc::sysinit:/etc/rc.sysinit
rs:S1:wait:/etc/rc.single
rm:2345:wait:/etc/rc.multi
rh:06:wait:/etc/rc.shutdown
su:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin -p

# -8 options fixes umlauts problem on login
#c1:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty1 linux
c2:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty2 linux
c3:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty3 linux
c4:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty4 linux
c5:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty5 linux
c6:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty6 linux

# Serial Virtual Console for KVM and others VMs
#s0:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 9600 ttyS0 linux

# Hypervisor Virtual Console for Xen and KVM
#h0:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 hvc0 linux

ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t3 -r now

# Example lines for starting a login manager
#x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/xdm -nodaemon
#x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/gdm -nodaemon
#x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/kdm -nodaemon
x:45:respawn:/usr/bin/slim >/dev/null 2>&1

# End of file
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `who` relies on the `/var/run/utmp` or the `/var/run/wtmp` file to determine logins.  Check for an issue with your /var partition or permissions of that file/directory.